# Send extra parameter to action on form submission in yii2

Tags: javascript, forms, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a gridview of `checkin` model with checkbox action column
and on the same view i have form of model `message` with 2 field `message` and `fileinput` but i want to send one more data on the submit button click of `message` model form which is the keys of checkbox.

How can i so that?
it can be done only via `javascript` or there is some other technique as well?

here is my grid and view code

```
<div class="row">
<p>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger','id'=>'sendMessage']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>



  </p>
</div>
<div class="checkin-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

 <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'checkin-grid', 'timeout' => false]); ?>

 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'showOnEmpty'=>true,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'user_id',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'value' => 'users.email',
            ],
            'user_type',
        ],
    ]);
 ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

And here is my `checkin/index` code where i can access the `message` and `fileinput` but i want list of `keys` as well...
So user must check at least one row before sending message

```
 public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Message();
    $searchModel = new CheckinSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the gridview inside the form?

Comment: @topher no i havent tried that but i am trying that now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your Message model adding the fields you need

```
class Message extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public $yourField;    

    public static function tableName()
    {
       ...
    }
```

this way in your model you have one more field not mapped to database and yon can use for your need....

When you submit your value, the submit related action you shuold manage the models like this way

```
   $models = $dataProvider->getModels();
   if (Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($models)) {  

    ...... your code for models managemnt



  }
```

F

Comment: yeah but how can i send the data of gridview checked column via that?

Comment: when you submit your data. In this case the submit related action should manage the models whit load multiple equivalent function based op posted value.

Comment: I have update the answer... I hope this could be useful